# stored procedures and temp tables

Tags: sql

I have to create a 10 stored procedure as follows:
In stored procedure # 1 I create temp table 1 and this temp table is used in stored procedure 2 to create another temp table and this new tem table is used in another STORED PROCEDURE and so on.

I am not sure how to create these stored procedure, because for these stored procedure I need to have temporary tables present in temdb.

Any help

Comment: This can be confusing with concurrent users...

Comment: Is stored procedure 1 calling stored procedure 2 itself so the calls are nested or are you executing the first proc then the 2nd proc in series?

Comment: no now I trying to create these stored procedures in database using sql server management studio. but since stored procedure 2 uses the temp table created in 1 . I have to first create stored procedure 1 and then create stored procedure 2. But after my stored procedure 1 runs successfully, temp table 1 is created but when I tried to create stored procedure 2 I get error INvalid object for temp table1

Comment: Why exactly does this need to be split out across 10 stored procedures? Is there a reason why it can't be done in one sproc?

Comment: Do you have to use temp tables? Why won't actual tables work? What happens when when the first stored proc gets called, and before it gets to the 10th stored proc, the first gets called by someone else? Can you explain what you're trying to do? Maybe it can be done another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you user Global Temporary Tables?

```
SELECT * INTO ##Users FROM UserTable
```

The Global temp tables will remain in tempdb until deleted and can be used across different stored procs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to name the table (or some of its columns) that's about to be created based on the data present in the temp table, you might want to resort to [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), since you can't use variables like this:

```
declare @foo varchar(50)
select @foo = tableName from #tempTable

create table @foo (fooColumn int)
```

But before you even think of using dynamic SQL, you've got to ask yourself whether you **really** need this solution.